# Bugzilla installation with MySQL 8.0 failing on adding new table groups

Tags: bugzilla, mysql-8.0

Trying to install bugzilla on ubuntu 18.04 with an external MySQL server which is running MySQL 8.0.

Not getting checksetup.pl to succeed. Its failing at the stage of "Adding new  table groups..." since it seems to be trying to create a table called groups, which is now a reserved word. The scripts arent using quotes. How do I get past this stage?

Seems to be raised here as a major issue a while ago
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424043 but no fix. Surely one could get past this?

Comment: Fork the repo, apply quotes around `groups` table in the schema file, install from your fork. Anyway, don’t use unmaintained software.

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know it was "no longer maintained". Will reconsider to start with it if thats case.

Comment: They had recently released Bugzilla 5.0.6, and despite it coming out in 2019 they still didn't fix the change.