# Is there a version of Bugzilla that works with MySQL version 8?

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

Apparently, the problem with Bugzilla and MySQL version 8 has been known for over 2 years.

I am running Bugzilla version 5. When my website provider upgraded my server to MySQL version 8, Bugzilla started throwing errors like the ones reported 2 years ago.

I have not been able to find any version of Bugzilla that mentions this error in its Release Notes. What version should I upgrade to?

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1497042 says:

> This will be in 5.0.6

However, a [comment on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377888/bugzilla-installation-with-mysql-8-0-failing-on-adding-new-table-groups) claims that 5.0.6 didn't fix the issue. That was the most recent release on the 5.0 branch, according to https://www.bugzilla.org/releases/. So you might have to try the 5.1 branch.

If you have further compatibility issues, I think the best place to report it would be the site for Bugzilla issues (the link I gave above).

You may even have to fix the code in Bugzilla yourself. This is not rocket science, I had to modify Bugzilla once for a project.